# Where do you flee when the zomghost-quarantine fails?

Tags: magic, apocalypse, modern-age, zombies

This is a shift from the traditional **"how to survive a zombie outbreak": zomghost-Edition!**

Lets say this year several small objects land on earth spreading an interdimensional pathogen. People start dying of necrosis and gangrene. But this is not the end - Scientist discover that this pathogen is a bioweapon from another reality!

24 hours after the first deaths strange specters start killing people at an alarming rate. They are the spirits of the infected with a zombie-like behaviour.

The zombified spirits are intangible and have the ability to pass through matter but for some reason they can bite, grab people and infect humans with their ethereal bodies. Sunlight (UV rays) can kill the ghosts, so they only show at night and survive the day in dark/wet places. Fire and heat can keep them at distance, so you only need a candle to protect yourself. Light bulbs don't work and black light can reveal the presence of hidden ghosts at day.

Electricity can kill the zomghosts too, so a hand taser is a good weapon against a single attacker. They are similar to new londo ghosts in dark souls, but they cannot fly. They are using matter as ¨stairs¨ instead. [image]

The outbreak starts in Mexico city, Texas and Calgary. These cities will be put under quarantine and after 48 hours all citizens are zom-ghost-ified.

If the quarantine fails and all zomghosts escape: **Where can you flee to survive and build a safehouse to spend the rest of your life?**

Your own starting point is several driving hours away from each of the mentioned cities. You can choose the exact spot.

Comment: You should add the title to the body, as your body currently doesn't contain a question. And what exactly do you mean by "survive"? Should humanity survive? A single village? Just you and two to three people? How many people are killed before everyone starts realising they are attacked by zomghosts?

Comment: @Secespitus lets say each month 0.5% of the population dies.Big cities population die 10% every night,Im not good with math ya know...

Comment: In such a scenario you don't have to be too specific with the math if you don't want to have a sciency answer. It's just a difference if there are 2 - 3 zomghosts per living person or if there are 10 living people for every zomghost at the start of what you are asking us. You used the words "alarming rate" which indicate a lot of zomghosts. A lot of until then unknown enemies is a big problem. If your protagonist is one of the first to notice that there are just 100 zomghosts in the last 48 hours he has a much higher chance of survival then someone realising his whole city is zom-ghost-ified

Comment: @AlexDarkshine, Your question borders on idea-generation, and it is also rather broad. I suggest that you re-structure your question a bit. I usually recommend people to follow the structure **Premise**, **Problem**, **Query**. Ok, so you have the premise bit done... sorta. It is very fuzzy and does not really portray the initial stages of the outbreak. Here things could go in **wildly** diverging paths. That should be clarified. Second: what the is **problem** you are facing as an author? Where have you gotten stuck? What information are you missing? What is it that you need **help** with?

Comment: And lastly: **Query**... this is where you ask "Who, What, When and Where. Then Whither, Whether, Whence and Wherefore to follow and one big side-order of WHY"... the question that — if you get it answered — solves your problem. Try this structure and I think you will find you get better answers. :)

Comment: Adding to what @MichaelK just said: we have a [Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Meta where you can post a question and get feedback on the style before releasing it onto the main site. This helps in sorting problems out before anyone on the main site sees the question, which often leads to better acceptance of questions, resulting in more views/ upvotes/ answers and higher quality answers.

Comment: Well,Ill do it later,I need to sleep and i dont have more tobacco or coffee.

Comment: A little hint from my side: you should keep questions open for at least one or two days, as according to my experience, it may take some time to find the question and some more time to write an answer to it. If there is already an accepted answer other users might be discouraged from writing additional answers. And people on this site live all over the world in different time zones - accepting something after only 3 hours may lead to people never being able to read your question (as most of us probably have a job). Give the people some time please, you only got ~70 views till now.

Comment: You say electricity can be used as a weapon against the zomghosts, but is there a minimum voltage/current/wattage before it is effective? I imagine that the zomghosts would have some trouble passing through walls with electrical wiring going through them.

Comment: @AlexDarkshine I am interested: why did you manually add "[on hold]" to the end of your title through editing your question?

Comment: @Secespitus Because i had 4 votes to close the question,And i say,Why not?

Comment: @AlexDarkshine Well, that's certainly an interesting take on the matter. Keep in mind that "[on hold]" has a specific meaning here and that adding this does not mean really putting it on hold. You certainly confused me with this and now it say "[on hold] [on hold]" which will certainly confuse others :D Please edit your question when you have the time and maybe post on Meta and go to the chat once you did so. I think your question could be reopened with some work.

Comment: @AlexDarkshine I suggested a bigger edit. If it gets approved you can have a look at it. Maybe this will get you started with the editing. Come to the chat/ meta and ping me or others if you need help or further feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Electric fences, military equipped with tasers and electric nets

I'm assuming that, because the starting places are high profile cities with high populations that we will notice but the problem won't spread too quick (why would the ghosts move from a densely populated city when they can feed inside).

I'm also going to assume that this extreme case will be taken seriously by governments all over the world.

Firstly we build an electric fence around these cities, whilst we're doing this we have large fires (perhaps gas powered) dotted around to protect the fence builders with teams of taser armed people to protect them.

Once the fences are built you go in by day and hunt the ghosts - perhaps even creating particularly dark and damp areas which will attract them and you can routinely clear these out. As areas of the city area cleared we can bring the electric fence forward, closing the ghosts in more and more.

Answer (score 2):

These zomghost do not stand fire, electricity and UV light.

UV light can be generated if you have electricity and a UV lamp, fire can be generated if you have wood.

Having electricity relies on other humans being alive or having fuel to run a generator, so it may become an issue in the long term, unless you manage to have some photovoltaic modules, you can manage to keep batteries charged and use the batteries to feed some UV lights shining the surrounding of your shelter.

Find a place with plenty of wood (close to a forest), and set the abit of sleeping with the fireplace lit on.
When you venture the woods for chopping wood, take with you a torch (woods can be dark and humid).

Use mirrors to reflect sunlight (when possible) into dark places you want to clean before entering.